# docker-compose: console does not return to host when creating database container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a postgresql docker container using docker-compose, but it seems that when I use a pre-ready postgresql image the console never return to the host, and if I hit Ctrl+C the container ends up being stoped. Here is what I got:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    container_name: database_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_database
    image: database:tag
    expose:
      - "5432"
```

**Dockerfile_database**

```
FROM library/postgres
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**init.sql**

```
CREATE USER usuario WITH PASSWORD 'senha';
CREATE DATABASE telesaude;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE telesaude TO usuario;
```

and during the container creation the console shows some postgresql logs, such as this:

```
Building database
Step 1/2 : FROM library/postgres
 ---> 4023a747a01a
Step 2/2 : ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
 ---> e264774d1f0b
Removing intermediate container 8df766b5a9f2
Successfully built e264774d1f0b
WARNING: Image for service database was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating database_server
Attaching to database_server
database_server | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
database_server | This user must also own the server process.
database_server | 
database_server | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
database_server | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
database_server | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
database_server | 
database_server | Data page checksums are disabled.
database_server | 
database_server | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
database_server | creating subdirectories ... ok
database_server | selecting default max_connections ... 100
database_server | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
database_server | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
database_server | creating configuration files ... ok
database_server | running bootstrap script ... ok
database_server | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
database_server | syncing data to disk ... 
database_server | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
database_server | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
database_server | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
database_server | ok
database_server | 
database_server | Success. You can now start the database server using:
database_server | 
database_server |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
database_server | 
database_server | ****************************************************
database_server | WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
database_server |          This will allow anyone with access to the
database_server |          Postgres port to access your database. In
database_server |          Docker's default configuration, this is
database_server |          effectively any other container on the same
database_server |          system.
database_server | 
database_server |          Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
database_server |          it in "docker run".
database_server | ****************************************************
database_server | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-02 21:15:46 UTC
database_server | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
database_server | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
database_server | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
database_server |  done
database_server | server started
database_server | ALTER ROLE
database_server | 
database_server | 
database_server | /docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
database_server | CREATE ROLE
database_server | CREATE DATABASE
database_server | GRANT
database_server | 
database_server | 
database_server | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
database_server | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
database_server | waiting for server to shut down...LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
database_server | .LOG:  shutting down
database_server | LOG:  database system is shut down
database_server |  done
database_server | server stopped
database_server | 
database_server | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
database_server | 
database_server | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-02 21:15:49 UTC
database_server | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
database_server | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
database_server | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
(console never returns to host after this)
```

What should I do so the container keeps running/started and the console returns to host? **I have to use docker-compose.** Can't use docker run -d ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run the container in the background with compose, use the detach option:

```
docker-compose up -d
```